# How to migrate a Linux server in Azure to AWS?

Tags: linux, azure, amazon-web-services

I am trying to migrate a Linux Server from Azure to AWS.
Is there any tool or plugin available to do so or i need to start from fresh?

Although there is import/export utility available in AWS which works with VMware vsphere . Is there any similar utility available with Azure so that i could import the VM into Vsphere and later export to AWS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to create a new server with the same linux flavor and version that you are currently running.  Don't try to upgrade versions at the same time.

Then you can use this fancy rsync script described below.  It is a few years old but the concept is sound.

Here is a long write up of the process

http://cloudnull.io/2012/07/cloud-server-migration/#migrate-using-rsync-the-easy-way

The github source of the code is this
https://github.com/cloudnull/InstanceSync